# KnockoutJS and Property-Dependent Create/Edit-View (Master/Detail Scenario)

Tags: mvvm, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, master-detail

I am having trouble creating a property-dependent create/edit-view in KnockoutJS.

Here's the thing: everything I create are "People" of sorts - it could be a Healthcare Professional, Plumber, Mechanic or Engineer. Depending on what kind/type of person it is, I need to enter different data.

Here an example:

```
Healthcare Professional: Name, Telephone, Hospital, etc.
Plumber: Name, Telephone, Crafts, etc.
Engineer: Name, Telephone, Specialities, etc.
```

What I **can** do is create properties on my ViewModels such as "showCity", "showHospital" and so on to hide individual form-fields.

However, for the sake of separation, I would like to use entirely different forms: again, I could set the respective form to only show if the condition is met.

However, I would like KnockoutJS to **only** render the respective form that should be used (the Person's type is always determined when it is first created - it cannot be changed).

What I don't end-up doing is have one form that is shown and ten that are there (and data-bound) but hidden.

I tried using the "if" binding like so: `<div data-bind="with: $root.selectedPerson"><form data-bind="if: $data.type='mathematician'"></form></div>`, but to no avail.

Would anybody know what the best-practice is in this case?

Comment: I would try looking at templating out the forms.  So each type of person has a specific template that you render when needed

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, that would take me back to my "display only the form which is needed" solution (visible: $data.isEngineer). I am looking for a solution which renders the required form **only**. Otherwise, I will end-up with lots of data-bound, unused forms in the DOM.

Comment: Well they aren't quite sitting in the DOM, but in script tags.  In your People classes you would define what template to use, and then on your view, would do something like `<div data-bind="template: { name: yourTemplateProperty, data: buyer }"></div>`

Comment: @JDR, no matter how you slice it, you're either going to have multiple templates on your page or multiple forms with `if` bindings determining if the inner html should be rendered or not.  The `if` binding is great but it comes with some cost of having to add/remove the form from the DOM.  The `visible` binding might be better as it just shows/hides it.  I think templating would be the best solution as @Thewads suggested.

Comment: Yes, I am beginning to realise that as well now. I did not think of dynamically binding a template but it sounds like the ideal solution in my case. Hence, a thumbs-up for Thewads. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` binding is setting the `$data.type` value, not comparing it.  Try:

```
<div data-bind="with: $root.selectedPerson"><form data-bind="if: $data.type() === 'mathematician'"></form></div>
```

Although this is fine, I always try to avoid code in my data-binding markup.  I would try and create a computed that would return the resulting true/false of the comparison, but in your situation, you would need one for each person type, and that would get tricky.  For that, I would turn to [templates](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html).  You could do:

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: $root.selectedPerson().type, data: $root.selectedPerson }"></div>
<script type="text/html" id="mathematician">...</script>
<script type="text/html" id="plumber">...</script>
```

*Note: As of KO version 2.3.0, the `name` property of the `template` binding can accept observables.  If you're using a previous version, be sure to call the observable in the binding: `name: $root.selectedPerson().type()`

Comment: The template-based solution seems ideal now that I am seeing it in action. This worked a charm and thank you for the detailed explanation (also with regards to v2.3). :-)